# EF Reverse POCO Generator: Failed to load provider EntityClient using .net core appsettings.json

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, poco

I tried

- set connection string of "appsettings.json" name to "Settings.ConnectionStringName" in database.tt in .net core and kept getting
- kept getting "Running transformation: Failed to find providerName in the connection string" error when database.tt was saved.
- copied connection string to "Settings.ConnectionStringName" from "appsettings.json", btw, everything works well in code first EF project.

Settings.ConnectionStringName = "server=XXXX; Database=TCS_Shenyi;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";

I still get the same error:

> EF Reverse POCO Generator: Failed to load provider EntityClient using .net core appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

1. The v2 is not compatible with .Net Core. Please use this one located on [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/huxxlel9irlgjp2/ReversePoco.7z?dl=0)
   This is the new v3 which is not yet released, and is compatible with .net core 2 & 3
2. Modify database.tt setting of following items

   - Settings.ConnectionString  from your appsettings.json
   - Settings.ConnectionStringName from your appsettings.json
   - Settings.TemplateType = TemplateType.EfCore2; (or 3, etc)
   - Settings.GeneratorType = GeneratorType.EfCore;

Otherwise, you will get following error.
[Replace EF 6.0 with EF core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U50Ar.png)